# Keyboard input error

Tags: java, android, input

I am having issues getting keyboard input for my game. I am currently just trying to get it to print either "KEY DOWN" or "KEY UP" to the log to see that it worked. All I get when I press any keys (whether it is the menu key or any other keys on my phone's physical keyboard), is a log printout saying:

01-20 02:53:57.718: WARN/System.err(13847): No Keyboard Setting saved.

I don't know what that means, and a google search has not been helpful. I did not put that log output in myself. I am basing my game off the lunar lander example. Has anyone seen this before?

The code I am using to test:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
            {
                Log.i("myActivity","KEY DOWN");
                return true;
            }
    else return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
            {
                Log.i("myActivity","KEY UP");
                return true;
            }
    else return false;
}
```

EDIT: Note that it never prints out either KEY DOWN or KEY UP, and even if I move either log output out of the "if (keycode==...)" section, it still doesnt run.

Comment: Where are your onkeydown, onkeyup contained?  What has focus when you are doing this?

Comment: They are contained in my main view thread. Touch input works perfectly well in this thread. I call "setFocusable(true);" in the constructor.

Comment: This is amazingly frustrating. Does anyone have any ideas at all? I can't seem to fix it :S.

Comment: Fixed it, I just needed to enable 'setFocusableInTouchMode'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding 'setFocusableInTouchMode(true);' to the constructor.